# Generating non-normal correlated data for mediation analysis?

Tags: r, simulation, mediation

For a simulation study I have to generate data according to a trivariate mediation model (Baron & Kennys causal step approach). Assuming $X$, $M$, and $Y$ are continuous variables of sample size $n$, the following regression equations constitute the data generating process:

$M = \alpha + aX + \epsilon$

$Y = \alpha + cX + bM + \epsilon$

Additionally, $X$ is not normally distributed, but is sampled from a distribution with skewness. I chose log-normal distribution in my current R implementation (see below). Sample size is also highly variable, starting at $n = 15$ and going up to $n = 15.000$.

Here is my admittedly really primitive and inefficient code:

Sample from `rlnorm()` until a random sample with desired skewness is found (for clarification: `tol` refers to a tolerance parameter set to $.01$).

```
library(moments)
s <- 1 # desired skewness
tol <- .01
n <- 20
a <- b <- c <- .59
skewness <- sqrt(log(-1+2^(1/3)/(2+s^2+sqrt(4*s^2+s^4))^(1/3)+(2+s^2+sqrt(4*s^2+s^4))^(1/3)/2^(1/3)))

repeat{X <- rlnorm(n=n, meanlog=0, sdlog=skewness)
    if (skewness(X) > (skewness - tol) && skewness(X) < (skewness + tol)) {break}
}
```

Then calculate $M$ and $Y$ from $X$ in a similar fashion and according to the regression equations above (where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the correlations between the variables):

```
repeat{
    M <- a * X + rnorm(n)
    if (cor(X, M) > (a - tol) && cor(X, M) < (a + tol)) {break}
}

repeat{
    Y <- c * X + b * M + rnorm(n)
    if (cor(Y, X) > (c - tol) && cor(Y, X) < (c + tol) &&
        cor(Y, M) > (b - tol) && cor(Y, M) < (b + tol)) {break}
}
```

Again, this code is woefully ineffective and is only applicable for very low $n$, as the computation time is pretty low for small samples. Once higher sample sizes are reached (about $n=200$), it stops working altogether.

So here are my actual questions:

- Is there a way to generate intercorrelated data ($X$, $M$ and $Y$) when $X$ isn't normally distributed and therefore `mvrnorm` from the `MASS` package can't be used? Also the correlation between the variables has to be either an exact value, or within a certain range ($\pm$ tolerance).
- Assuming it can be done theoretically (which I am quite sure of), how can it be implemented in `R`?